# Methods are not executed in the for (if-else) loop and returns me the original object

Tags: java, arrays, nested

I have an array of moves to be made a to a rubiks cube i.e.:

```
String[] clockwiseMoves = new String[6];
```

whereby the moves are denoted as F(front), R(right), U(up), L(left), B(back), D(down) (e.g. when F is executed, you are to rotated the front face of the cube clockwise). Given an instance of `Rubik` (from Rubik class) is instantiated, I want it to execute every move in the my `clockwiseMoves` array.

In my Rubik class, I have these methods:

1. `public Rubik frontfaceRight()`: which rotates the front face of the Rubik to the right and return a new instance of Rubik which has been rotated.
2. `public Rubik rightfaceRight()`: which rotates the right face of the Rubik to the right and return a new instance of Rubik which has been rotated.
3. `public Rubik upfaceRight()`: which rotates the up face of the Rubik to the right and return a new instance of Rubik which has been rotated.
4. `public Rubik leftfaceRight()`: which rotates the left face of the Rubik to the right and return a new instance of Rubik which has been rotated.
5. `public Rubik backfaceRight()`: which rotates the back face of the Rubik to the right and return a new instance of Rubik which has been rotated.
6. `public Rubik downfaceRight()`: which rotates the down face of the Rubik to the right and return a new instance of Rubik which has been rotated.

Given these, I have come up with the following:

```
for (int j = 0; j<clockwiseMoves.length; j++){

      if (cwMethods[j].equals("F")){
        originalRubik.frontfaceRight();
      }

      else if (cwMethods[j].equals("R")){
        originalRubik.rightfaceRight();
      }

      else if (cwMethods[j].equals("U")){
        originalRubik.upfaceRight();
      }

      else if (cwMethods[j].equals("L")){
        originalRubik.leftfaceRight();
      }

      else if (cwMethods[j].equals("B")){
        originalRubik.backfaceRight();
      }

      else if (cwMethods[j].equals("D")){
        originalRubik.downfaceRight();
      }
    }

System.out.println(originalRubik);
```

However, my printed output gives me the intial `Rubik` before it went through the for loop, meaning that the methods in the for loop were not executed. May I know how to correct my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that those methods return a ***new*** instance of `Rubik`, so when you process the actions in the `if-else` blocks you are not assigning the new instance to the `originalRubik` variable and it still points to the initial instance of `Rubik`.

So you need to capture the new instance of the `Rubik` and assign it to the `originalRubik` varaible to see the changes.

```
for (int j = 0; j<clockwiseMoves.length; j++){

  if (cwMethods[j].equals("F")){
    originalRubik = originalRubik.frontfaceRight();
  }

  else if (cwMethods[j].equals("R")){
    originalRubik = originalRubik.rightfaceRight();
  }

  else if (cwMethods[j].equals("U")){
    originalRubik = originalRubik.upfaceRight();
  }

  else if (cwMethods[j].equals("L")){
    originalRubik = originalRubik.leftfaceRight();
  }

  else if (cwMethods[j].equals("B")){
    originalRubik = originalRubik.backfaceRight();
  }

  else if (cwMethods[j].equals("D")){
    originalRubik = originalRubik.downfaceRight();
  }
}

System.out.println(originalRubik);
```